# VBA Access Message Box woes

Tags: vba, msgbox

I followed a few simple comments on how to pop a confirmation box before executing a script, but sadly, if I press yes, the script doesn't run.

```
Private Sub Overwrite_Btn_Click()
    If MsgBox("Yes?", vbOKCancel) = ok Then
        Me.Product_Quantity = Me.Quantity_Input
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying to set `Product_Quantity` equaling `Quantity_Input`, and although it works without the MsgBox command, it doesn't with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `If MsgBox("Yes?", vbOKCancel) = ok Then` try: `If MsgBox("Yes?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then`

Typically the interactions with forms will return one constant from a set of several constants. Those are catalogged in *enums*. In this case you have several constants in the `VbMsgBoxResult` class, and `vbOK` is a constant with value 1, which is returned from clicking the ok button.

Actually, `If MsgBox("Yes?", vbOKCancel) = 1 Then` would work as well, but it is harder to remember that clicking Ok returns 1 then simply stating a constant named `vbOK`

In object explorer (F2 on the VBE), searching for `VbMsgBoxResult` will give all possible results that comes from interacting with a message box.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/constants/msgbox_ret.php

1) Dim a variable as integer.

2) Check for value of integer equal to 6, or check for vbYess

3) ?????

4) Profit

borrowed from link

```
 Dim LResponse As Integer

 LResponse = MsgBox("Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Continue")

 If LResponse = vbYes Then
    {...statements...}
 Else
    {...statements...}
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Single line:

```
If MsgBox("Yes?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOk then Exit Sub

'continue code here.
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**MsgBox Function** (Office/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/msgbox-function)